# The missing system tray icons on Fedora 19 Desktop Edition

Tags: fedora, gnome, notification-area

Once installing Fedora 19 Desktop Edition, I run the systray of Qt Example. But I could not look for the system tray icon.

There is no Notification area in the Activities overview.

Please let me know to display the notification area or the tray icon.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 same problem here, Pidgin icon is not appearing..

Comment: Just figured out, moving the mouse to the bottom right corner of the screen helped to find out pidgin...

Comment: I installed pidgin and dropbox, but those are missing in spite of moving the mouse to the bottom right corner.

Comment: I tested on the Virtual Box. Is it the related with?

Comment: I just discovered one more way to display notifications using Super+M ( I call it windows key :-) ) . Let me know this worked for you or not.. ( Discovered at https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.8/more-core-ux.html.en )

Comment: It works on the Virtualbox. Thanks.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com 

Comment: On Fedora 20, had the same problem with Skype and Dropbox. Solved using **Windows key+M**

Answer (score 18):

Moving your mouse quickly to the bottom right should display the Message Tray. If it doesn't work, use Super+M (windows key+M).

If you're running Synergy, the pressure sensitivity isn't working and you won't be able to use the mouse, because of this [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=972244). You must use Super+M.

Comment: There is some way to **change** this keyboard shortcut???? I'm running gnome shell on a VM over OSX (Super+M is used for minimizing the current application on OSX). :-(

Comment: You can set your VM to use shortcuts on each operating system respectively, and mark the answer as correct since it answers successfully your question.

Answer (score 1):

Today I installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and I couldn't find the Message Tray.
Moving the mouse down I made it appear some times. Finally I realized that it opened every time I moved my finger down on the touchpad two times.
I don't know if this interaction is intended or it is just a bug.

Super+M works too, thanks!

Comment: There's a little exclamation mark on GNOME 3.8+, at least, that you can click on to bring up the message tray too. GNOME 3.8 is what comes with Fedora 19.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install the [Frippery Bottom Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/).

[image: ss of panel]

The little exclamation point icon on the bar can be clicked to bring up the Message Tray too.

[image: message tray]

Clicking an item from the tray area or pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel it, will remove the focus on the tray.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ucbunn/comment/i69dpo5/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) from this reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ucbunn/no_application_icons_displayed_in_the_tray/) suggests to install [AppIndicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) support from Gnome extensions. This extension is responsible for showing system tray icons in Gnome. It comes preinstalled in Ubuntu as stated in the answer, but not on Fedora.

By default, you should click the date-time at the center of the status bar to view notifications. Alternatively, <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut also does the same work.